# Discrete Math Question on Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove, using double inclusion, that if $A = C$ and $B = C$, then $A = B$, whatever the sets $A, B$ and $C$.

First of all, can someone define double inclusion? And then can he/she prove it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Double inclusion" is a way of showing that $A = B$: you show that $A \subseteq B$ and that $B \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\subseteq$ is transitive. So suppose you have that $A = C$, this means that $A \subseteq C$. You also have that $B = C$: in particular, $C \subseteq B$. What can you deduce of the relationship between $A$ and $B$? You can then mirror this argument to show the other part.

Comment: So, if A = C, then A ⊆ C and C ⊆ A?